# Is it possible to use clojure's gen-class macro to generate a class with static fields?

Tags: static, clojure, field, gen-class

Can the following class be generated using Clojure's gen-class macro?

```
public class Test {
    public static final String TEST_NAME = "This test's name.";
}
```

If not, why not?

Comment: `why not?` Because that's not the purpose of Clojure.

Comment: How might one distinguish the 'purpose' of clojure with respect to the existence of gen-class when it doesn't support for static fields?  In other words:  Why provide the facility to create raw java classes without providing the mechanism for setting static fields.  I'm not  picking a fight.  I really like Clojure.  I just can't seem to find anywhere a rationale for this decision.

Comment: Gen-class is for introp, that is it attempts to give you the power to create the kind of classes demanded by other java libs. It is rare for a java lib to require you provide a class with a particular static field.

Comment: Thank you.  That's the best explanation I've seen.

Comment: Well, then, I'll just copy that on down...

Answer (score 1):

No, gen-class can't generate static fields because gen-class is for introp. It attempts to give you the power to create the kind of classes demanded by other java libs.  It is rare for a java lib to require that you provide a class with a particular static field.